# How to determine ranking of significance of independent factors (e.g. age, gender, occupation) on single dependent factor (e.g. smoker or not smoker)?

Tags: regression

I've done a survey looking at binary outcomes (smoking or not smoking) with a number of independent factors (mostly sociodemographic factors e.g. household income, age, gender, race etc.) I'd like to see how to rank the significance of factors impacting the outcome. How should I go about this?

Ideas:

- Multivariate log regression and then ranking the parameters? Does that make sense?

Thanks anyone for their help!